# View and communicate with network devices through browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a project that captures the user's desktop and stream it wirelessly to a device on the local network. I am considering developping a browser extension to do this. However, I am having a hard time figuring out if this is possible using javascript and the browser's API.

Specifically, I need to know if the extension will be able to see the devices connected to the local network and connect with them. Has anyone here done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome extension - most certainly no, not without a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) module.

A Chrome app has access to [TCP/UDP client capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sockets), so depending on your protocol the answer is "maybe".  See code [here](https://github.com/KensakuKOMATSU/chrome-upnp) for a UPnP device discovery example - but do note this was back when the API was experimental.

With a Native Host, you can possibly do a lot. This restricts distribution possibilities (can't bundle the host module in the Web Store), but that may or may not be a concern for you.